# Vue Tailwind CSS "laggy" transitions on MacOS/iOS

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

When testing the below Vue component on my iPhone or MacBook (differing results on chrome/safari), I have stuttery/laggy transitions when different classes are toggled on or off. This particular example is of a Vertical Navigation menu, that is hidden off screen on mobile, then moved into position when a button is clicked.

On iOS safari, the transition is slow and individual frames are visible. On iOS Chrome the menu "snaps" into place, skipping the transition altogether. On MacOS Chrome/Safari, the transition lags a small amount.

```html
<template>
  <div class="w-0 md:w-1/5 absolute sm:relative sm:block h-full transform top-0 w-64 select-none
      overflow-auto ease-in-out transition-all duration-300 z-30 -translate-x-[300px] md:translate-x-0 overflow-y-hidden" :class="{'-translate-x-0': open}" v-click-outside="toggleMobileNav">
    <aside class="h-full" aria-label="Sidebar">
      <div class="py-4 px-3 bg-white dark:bg-primary-dark h-full overflow-y-auto shadow-lg" >
...continues
```

Find below my Tailwind CSS config (I'm probably missing an option):

```js
module.exports = {
    darkMode: "class",
    theme: {
        extend: {
            zIndex: {
                '-10': '-10',
            },
            colors: {
                'primary': '#1be396',
                'primary-dark': '#181818',
                'primary-dark-lighter': '#232325',
                'danger': '#e11d48',
                'info': '#3083DC',
                'warning': '#FCA311',
            }
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        require('tailwind-scrollbar'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
    variants: {
        scrollbar: ['rounded']
    },
    content: [
        `components/**/*.{vue,js}`,
        `layouts/**/*.vue`,
        `pages/**/*.vue`,
        `composables/**/*.{js,ts}`,
        `plugins/**/*.{js,ts}`,
        `App.{js,ts,vue}`,
        `app.{js,ts,vue}`
    ]
}
```